# Why class member function destroies the memory allocated for a pointer argument?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, heap-memory

From I know, c++ allocates the memory for a pointer in the heap which will not be free automatically when the function exits. But after the codes below run, I find that the pointer a is null even if it is allocated some space in a class member function.

```
#include "string"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Test
{
public:
    void test(int *a) {
        if (a == 0)
        {
            a = new int[10];
            bool a_is_null = (a == 0);
            cout << "in class member function, after allocated, a is null or not?:" << a_is_null << endl;
        }
    };
};
int main() {
    int *a = 0;

    bool a_is_null = (a == 0);
    cout << "in main function, before allocated, a is null or not?:" << a_is_null << endl;

    Test t;
    t.test(a);

    a_is_null = (a == 0);
    cout << "in main function, after allocated, a is null or not?:" << a_is_null << endl;

    delete[] a;
    cin;
}
```

[This is the conducting result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQ4xH.png)

Can anyone tell me why?

Does the test function destroy the memory of `new int[10]` when it exits? and so that the pointer a is still null after that.

Comment: "c++ allocates the memory for a pointer in the heap" – no, where did you get that wrong information from?

Comment: Yeah. You are right. It should be that the memory allocated by operator 'new' is in the heap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pointer is like any other variable, and you are passing it by value in the line

```
t.test(a);
```

Therefore the pointer is not modified after the function exits. Pass it by reference and you'll see the difference, i.e. declare

```
void Test::test(int* &a) { ...}
```

<kbd>[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3692d1421b8ac418)</kbd>

Comment: Yes. Things changed based on your advice. Thank you.